# How to merge duplicate column names into into one cell in pandas dataframe/excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter, xlrd

I'm struggling to merge header cell duplicate column names into one.

input is like below:

[image]

expected output like below:

[image]